# Getting error while running cucumber java file in junit

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

I am running my cucumber program from junit and I always get an error says:

```
TestRunner (1)
cucumber.TestRunner
initializationError(cucumber.TestRunner)
```

Any idea why this error is occuring?
But when I run my `.feature` file, its executing smoothly.

My Stack Trace is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom2/Content
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:40)
at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.loadGlue(JavaBackend.java:86)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:91)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:69)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:65)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.createRuntime(Cucumber.java:78)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdom2.Content
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 28 more
```

Comment: Is the library jdom on your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Either rename the package or move your step-definition to something like "cucumber.steps" and exclude the cucumber-package using @CucumberOptions(glue = "cucumber.steps").
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cukes/TGocUmPr3Z4